# Next.JS dependency issue when installing

Tags: npm, next.js, dependencies, npm-install, package.json

I have this next.js project and this is the package.json file.

```js
{
  "name": "marketplace",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "doppler run next dev",
    "devstart": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prisma": "prisma format && prisma generate && prisma db push",
    "deploy": "node -r esm ./contracts/deploy.js",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/css": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@fl-did-registry/did-document": "^0.5.7",
    "@fl-did-registry/did-ipfs-store": "^0.5.2",
    "@fl-did-registry/did-nft-resolver": "^0.5.10",
    "@fl-did-registry/jwt": "^0.5.2",
    "@jeromevvb/equinox-lib": "^0.0.60",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.15.0",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^1.0.1",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^6.18.0",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.7.4",
    "@web3auth/web3auth": "^0.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "magic-sdk": "^8.1.0",
    "moralis": "^1.3.5",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-blockies": "^1.4.1",
    "react-detect-click-outside": "^1.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-is-mounted-hook": "^1.1.2",
    "react-moralis": "^1.3.2",
    "react-query": "^3.35.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-use-intercom": "^1.5.0",
    "viem": "^0.3.41",
    "wagmi": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.9",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.9.2",
    "@emotion/jest": "^11.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "prisma": "^4.15.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "twin.macro": "^2.8.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

When I try to run the npm install, it gives me the below errors.
[image]

Then as it says, I used **"typescript": "^5.0.4"** in package.json and again tried run npm install and run the project. Then it gives me below error.

[image]

Is there any solution for this? Thank You!